# Tor is not connecting on windows 7

Tags: censorship, firewall, blocked

I have tried using Bridges and all i get is this report:

`02/06/2016 19:46:45 p.m..800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/06/2016 19:46:48 p.m..700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/06/2016 19:46:55 p.m..700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
02/06/2016 19:46:55 p.m..700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
02/06/2016 19:46:55 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:46:55 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:46:55 p.m..900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:46:56 p.m..000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:46:56 p.m..000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:10 p.m..100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/06/2016 19:47:10 p.m..100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/06/2016 19:47:10 p.m..100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/06/2016 19:47:27 p.m..800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/06/2016 19:47:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:55 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:55 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:55 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 19:47:55 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:34 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:34 p.m..700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:34 p.m..800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:02:55 p.m..600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.*.*.*:* ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/06/2016 20:12:55 p.m..800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/06/2016 20:12:55 p.m..800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/06/2016 20:12:55 p.m..800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150`

Comment: OS? What AV do you use? Static or DHCP? Firewall, enabled/disabled?